# Every matrix $A$ with $\text{det}(A-A^T)=1$ can be realized as Seifert matrix

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

Let $A\in\text{Mat}(2n\times2n;\mathbb{Z})$ be an integer matrix with $\text{det}(A-A^T)=1$. I got told that every such matrix can be realized as Seifert matrix of a Seifert surface $F$ of a knot $K$ with an appropriate basis of $H_1(F;\mathbb{Z})$. I would be thankful for any reference on this statement or an argument how such a matrix can be realized as a Seifert matrix of some knot.

Comment: In `Kawauchi, Akio (2012) [1996]. A Survey of Knot Theory`, it is proven that every polynomial $p\in\mathbb{Z}[t]$ that is symmetric and $p(1)=\pm1$ is the Alexander polynomial of a knot. We can then see that $p(t)=\det(tA-A^T)$ satisfies those conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, it is a book.

Comment: yes I found it ;D thank you again!

Comment: Just for future reference it is Corollary 5.1.6 in Kawauchi, Akio (2012) [1996]. A Survey of Knot Theory

Comment: This may come a little late now, but I have a minor problem with your argument. In my opinion it only shows that $p(t):=\text{det}(tA-A^T)$ can be realized as Alexander polynomial of a knot. However this does not show that $A$ actually is a Seifert matrix of this knot, does it?

Comment: I understood the proof of Kawauchi, thus the question is obsolete. Thank you for the reference again!